# TYPO3 Spambot/Captcha for tx_form

Tags: typo3, captcha, typoscript, spam-prevention

I have search the internet for spambot/captcha plugin for tx_form.
But i can't find any with a working ex. can someone help ?

I have the following code, i just need to know how i add spambot protection/captcha, and what Extension can i use with tx_form.

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1.4

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
id = kontakt
method = post
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 1
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        recipientEmail = thomas@damain.dk
        senderEmail = noreplay@domain.dk
                senderNameField = name
        subject = dfgdfg hjemmeside henvendelse.
                messages {
                     success = Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage! Wir werden uns umgehend mit Ihnen in Verbindung setzen.
                     error = Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte wenden Sie sich an den webmaster.
                }
    }
}
10 = TEXTLINE
10 {
    name = Navn
    label {
        value = Navn
    }
}
20 = TEXTLINE
20 {
    name = firma
    label {
        value = Firmanavn
    }
}
30 = TEXTLINE
30 {
    name = Telefon
    label {
        value = Telefon nr.
    }
}
40 = SUBMIT
40 {
    name = 5
    value = Send
}
rules {
    1 = digit
    1 {
        breakOnError = 1
        showMessage = 
        message = Du kan kun bruge numre.
        error = Et telefon nr. består typisk af cifre.
        element = Telefon
    }
    2 = length
    2 {
        breakOnError = 1
        showMessage = 
        message = Fejl i længden af telefon nr.
        error = Det indtastede nr. er mindre end de påkrævet 8 cifre.
        minimum = 8
        maximum = 0
        element = Telefon
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any extension to do so.

Use the [powermail](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/powermail) extension to create a more advanced form and add captcha using sr_freecap or using the captcha extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for your request. Checkout the extension wt_spamshield (http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/wt_spamshield) and the manual (see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/wt_spamshield/1.1.1/Spamshield/ConfigurationOfSpamshield/UseWtSpamshieldWithDefault(typo3)Mailform/Index.html).

I'm the leader of the extension. If you have any question you can ask me here or via forge etc.

As you see form the example in the manual you can create a new rule set. Something like the following:

```
rules {
  1 = wtspamshield
  1 {
    element = msg
  }
  2 = wtspamshield
  2 {
    element = uid987651
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension for that. 
You can add a captcha from "recaptcha" using library jm_recaptcha. The extension is compatible with wizard.

[cdsrc_recaptcha_form](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cdsrc_recaptcha_form/)
[jm_recaptcha](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/jm_recaptcha)